# Why do I get a security warning in visual studio 2008 when creating a project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

This is the error, it's basically a security warning

[Warning message http://img357.imageshack.us/img357/7992/visualstudiowarninggr4.jpg](http://img357.imageshack.us/img357/7992/visualstudiowarninggr4.jpg)

(And here's the text grabbed off the dialog box)
Security Warning for WindowsApplication4 __________________________I
The WindowsApplication4 project file has been customized and could present a security risk by executing custom
build steps when opened in Microsoft Visual Studio. If this project came from an untrustwoithy source, it could
cause damage to your computer or compromise your private information.
More Details
Project load options
0 Load project for browsing
Opens the project in Microsoft Visual Studio with increased security. This option allows you to browse the
contents of the project, but some functionality, such as IntelliSense, is restricted, When a project is loaded
for browsing, actions such as building, cleaning, publishing, or opening designers could still remain unsafe.
Load project normally
Opens the project normally in Microsoft Visual Studio. Use this option if you trust the source and
understand the potential risks involved. Microsoft Visual Studio does not restrict any project
functionality and will not prompt you again for this project.
Ask me for every project in this solution
OK L Cancel

When click the more details button get this:

Microsoft Visual Studio ______
An item referring to the file was found in the project file
“C:\Users\mgriffiths\Documents\Visual Studio
2008\ProjectATemp\Win dowsApplication4\WindowsApplicdtion4\W in
dowsApplication4.vbproj”. Since this file is located within a system
directory, root directory, or network share, it could be harmful to write
to this file.
OK

Comment: -1 This question is unreadable which is why the answers are a pile of guesses. I'd like the last 2 minutes of my life back please.

Answer (score 5):

After playing around a bit (I'm using Windows XP), I found that VS resets the All Users Startup directory to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup. If this directory doesn't exist, it is reset to '' in the registry, and the error is displayed. Adding this directory corrected the issue. I've customized the location of my user directories, including Startup, and it doesn't seem to care about that (in Windows XP, at least).

Comment: Very bizarre. I've been getting this security warning error, *and* hanging when closing projects, and creating a Startup folder in All Users seems to have fixed both.

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting this issue for EVERY project. A quick, simple fix is to disable it in the registry. For Visual Studio 2008, this is at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Debugger\DisableAttachSecurityWarning
```

The value should currently be 0. Change it to 1, and you will never see the dialog again. And by never, I mean **never**, so be careful if you are loading projects where the security warning would actually be useful.

For Visual Studio 2005, you can find the key at the same place, but replacing "9.0" with "8.0".

If that doesn't do the trick, you might want to also make sure that the following two folders exist:

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
```

For some reason, Visual Studio 2008 will complain if it can't open those folders.

Comment: I had the problem as such, and realised that this was because I had moved the deleted the startup folder as part of a start menu cleanup, since then VS had been giving me the error, but re-creating this folder fixed it.

Comment: Changing the Registry value worked for me with VS 2005.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and finally found an answer that helped (Todd's answer here went into the right direction). Check out the response in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/33a7a870-bfd1-4d1f-8715-4becca47ef77):

> We're starting to understand the problem.  As a workaround can you please check to see if the following folder exists for your profile?
>
> C:\Users(user)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>
> If not, please create it and try again.  Please post back if this doesn't solve your problem.
>
> We know it is related to a Windows Known Folder not existing for a user profile.  If the folder above exists, you can also check to ensure you have the following folders: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It could be because your users 'Home' folder (Users\LOGINNAME) is a mapped network share. You could try placing your projects in another non-network shared folder...

Comment: This definitely sounds like the error message I had when I tried running VS projects over a network share.

Comment: sorry that's not it, as you can see in the error msg I'm running in my documents

Answer (score 2):

Security Warning occurs when some part of MSBuild project is customized.

[image: Visual Studio 2008 Security Warning]

If you are using your custom **.targets** file you need to register it - to let VS know that it is a safe item.

Write these 2 registry entries to do it:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<VS_VERSION>\MSBuild\SafeImports]
"<YOUR_NAME>"="<PATH\TO\YOUR\FILE.targets>"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<VS_VERSION>Exp\Configuration\MSBuild\SafeImports]
"<YOUR_NAME>"="<PATH\TO\YOUR\FILE.targets>"
```

where **VS_VERSION** is Visual Studio version as:
9.0 - Visual Studio 2008
10.0 - Visual Studio 2010 etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for that security warning dialog box:

- The project file contains one or more non-standard Import elements.
- The project file overrides one or more potentially unsafe targets.
- The project file overrides one or more potentially unsafe properties.
- The project file defines one or more potentially unsafe items.
- The project file contains one or more UsingTask elements.
- Project items are located in a potentially unsafe location.

More details are available on the [MSDN Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228217.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are running Vista and UAC is also running.  Are you an administrator on the computer?  One option is to stop the UAC service and try running VS2008 to see if you still get that message.  Another option is to take a look at the permissions on the 'C:\Users\mgriffiths' folder to confirm the permissions/system settings.

Let me know if this helps!
JFV

Comment: I do have vista but I don't have UAC running.
And my user is an administrator with "full control "access rights to everything in the folder.

Comment: Are you also in the 'Debugger Users' and 'VS Developers' Groups?  I'm looking through my system and I am also in those groups.  Another thing is I turned off Windows Security Center Prompts.  This might help you out as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript file is not "included" in your project, VS can't find it.  Try doing a refresh on the folder containing the file. That effectively includes the file in your web project (or site).  In solution explorer, highlight the web site project (or site), then click the refresh icon on the solution explorer toolbar.

--Monico

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with VS2008 on Windows 7

I've created the path C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup and it doesn't help me.

I've found that the right folder is %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Answer (score -3):

The following does the trick on XP. On this dialog:
Select "Load project normally" radio button.
Uncheck "Ask me for every project in this solution" checkbox.
Click OK.